# Error parsing info: Unable to retrieve video metadata

Tags: discord, discord.js, ytdl

I have made a music bot, and i get the error below everytime I play a song

```
Error parsing info: Unable to retrieve video metadata
```

I have googled and found other people who faced the same issue but got it fixed by uninstalling node-ytdl and reinstalling it or by updating to version 3.4.2, i have done both and neither worked.

A few others told that it worked once they started to use a vpn, however even while the bot is hosted on repl.it, i come across the same issue.I do not know how to change server on repl or if its even possible, however if any of you do know how to do so, I would appreciate it if you would tell me.

I am new to coding so please bear with me, thank you.

Comment: Can you share the original YouTube url?

Comment: @pierpy sorry for replying late, i had exams. by the original youtube url did you mean the video pattern or...?